# Dynamic sized string in C

Tags: c, string, dynamic, realloc, strcat

I have the following code and to edit the string of a "path" that I will be working on in a program that I am creating.

My problem is that I the code works, but I have no idea why or to be clearer I don't understand why `strcat` allows `src` to be appended to `dest`. Since everything is using dynamic strings shouldn't I have to `realloc dest`.  But when I try that, `realloc` fails

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char *src = argv[1];
        char *dest = argv[2];
        char *d_basedir;
        int s_length = strlen(src);

        printf("dest starts as %s: length %zu\n", dest, strlen(dest));
        printf("src starts as %s: length %zd\n", src, strlen(src));

        if(!(src[s_length - 1] == '/')) {
            if((d_basedir = strrchr(src, '/')+1) != NULL) {
                printf("basedir is %s\n", d_basedir);
                strcat(dest, d_basedir);
                printf("dest changed to %s: length %zd\n", dest, strlen(dest));
            }
        }

        printf("dest ends as %s: length %zd\n", dest, strlen(dest));

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot `realloc()` something you didn't obtain from `malloc()` (or its cousins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosted environment provides you with the `argv[]` array, but you didn't allocate this memory, so you shouldn't attempt to reallocate it. You shouldn't really modify `argv[]` at all. If you want to make modifications, make a copy of the string first (using `malloc` etc.) and at least then you can know for certain whether you have enough space or whether you need to use `realloc` before concatenating.

Comment: Modifying the elements of `argv[2]` string is perfectly defined, but writing past these elements is undefined.

Comment: It's defined but not ideal, especially for this situation.

Comment: the first printf  gives the length of argv[2] which is the exact length of dest. so wouldnt that mean there is a null character there at the end and appending to it should fail

Comment: @johnsoga: You can only safely assume that `argv[2]` has as many characters that `strlen()` says it does, plus one (for the null character). This will change depending on how your program is invoked from a command line, but you cannot assume it has any more space at the end to concatenate more characters. If you need more space, you'll need to make it yourself (using malloc or variable length array, etc.).

Comment: I understand that so by all logic then this should be failing everytime it runs but it doesn't so should I just consider it dumb luck that it continues to work

Comment: Undefined behaviour... Might work, might silently fail and introduce buffer overflow vulnerabilities that allow mischievous attacks on your network. Might cause nuclear missiles to be launched, if this code is in control of such a system. Undefined means the compiler is free to produce code that is unbound by the constraints of the C standard.

Comment: @johnsoga: The behaviour is *undefined*. This means that it may work (which is the worst possible outcome because it is not guaranteed to work, and you would be relying on something that is inherently unreliable). It also means it may not work. Some environments and some compilers may - and probably do - exhibit different behaviours, including anything from crashing, to partially working, to fully working. You never want to rely on undefined behaviour. In your particular scenario where it is working, the hosting environment has probably allocated more memory than it needs for `argv[2]`, but

Comment: you can't rely on that being the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcat(dest, d_basedir);
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
strcat(argv[2], d_basedir);
```

and it is undefined behavior. It may work today and fails tomorrow. You have the right to write to `argv[2][0]` up to `argv[2][strlen(argv[2])]` but writing past that element (what you are doing with your `strcat` call) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @johnsoga `strcat(argv[2],  d_basedir)` writes to `argv[2][strlen(argv[2])]`, `argv[2][strlen(argv[2]) + 1]`, `argv[2][strlen(argv[2]) + 2]`, etc. Writing to `argv[2][strlen(argv[2])]` is OK (the null terminator is part of the original string), but writing to `argv[2][strlen(argv[2]) + 1]` and the next elements is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It works becouse you are lucky. That's all ;-)

By appending to dest you are overwriting some memory your program have allocated, but it does not use it for anything important. So that's why it "works".

You cannot realloc memory that was not allocated by malloc. Arguments passed to main() are one of these parts of memory.

What you want is to malloc new memory big enough for new path, and then strcpy and strcat what you need into it.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` doesn't care about `dest`. It's just a pointer to char and that is sufficient for [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/).

Since `argv[2]` is from the environment, adding to dest (argv[2]) isn't allowed. The correct way is to allocate sufficient memory, copy `argv[2]` into it and append `d_basedir` to that

```
char *dest = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + strlen(d_basedir) + 1);
strcpy(dest, argv[2]);
strcat(dest, d_basedir);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use realloc/malloc for this sort of code.

You can use PATH_MAX (or in some cases MAX_PATH) to determine the longest path you will need.

```
 char dest[PATH_MAX]; 

 strcpy(dest, d_basedir);
 strcat(dest, argv[2]);
```

(Which is slightly different to what you've written, which appends src-path's d_basedir to the end of dest, which appears wrong to me)